# Deal with generated files for multiple users simultaneously

Tags: python, django

I am developing a website using django 1.8 and python3.4 with anaconda environment. Basically, A file and plot are generated and display on the web page after a user inputs parameters and submits it. Then the user can download the file and image.

My approach to handle the file storage is store them as static files and name them as "result.csv" and "plot.png".The files are totally different based on users' request. But if more than one user request something simultaneously, the system only save a file with a name. It is very dangerous.

I have no insight to deal with this situation. Could anyone give some suggestion or a direction for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Personally I would store them in the media folder.

Comment: @Wtower  The file and image are not uploaded by users, they are generated by the system, should they be put on MEDIA folder?

Comment: What does it matter if they are generated and not uploaded? With the static folder, next time that you make a new deployment and run collect static what will happen with the previously generated files? You would have to resolve this manually.

Comment: @Wtower, I think you are right, but what quite painful is that when users submit different request at same time, only one kind result for all the users, as I always name the generated file something like "result.csv". So the older file for a user will be override by a new file for others.

Comment: I tend to agree with the answer by Pynchia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this. The first ones that spring to mind are, assuming you want to keep one set of results per user (i.e. the last generated)

1- Create unique names based on the user-id. This allows you to access the files without first consulting the user data in the DB.

It also has the advantage of not having to delete previous versions of the files.

2- Create unique filenames with the `uuid` library module

```
import uuid
user_filename = uuid.uuid4()
csv_filename = user_filename+'.csv'
png_filename = user_filename+'.png'
```

and store the `user_filename` in the DB user record for later access.

3- Do the same but using a timestamp with enough resolution

Alternatively you can create a subdirectory with a unique name and store the files inside it with a static name for both.

Options 2 and 3 require you to remove previous versions of the files when generating new ones for the same user.

As mentioned by @Wtower, store the files in the MEDIA directory, maybe under a further subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you @Pynchia. Actually the previous version of the file is unnecessary to store, I prfer to using your second and third solutions. But I don't understand why you said that option 2 and 3 need to remove previous versions. Do you mean that previous one are removed automatically?

Comment: And another question, the ´user_filename´ is generated random, if it is stored in database, how to use it for later access? My application doesn't store user information in database, I use IP restriction to manage users.

Comment: OK, then use the IP as a user-ID and name the files using that

Comment: In the first case, using the user-id (in whatever form it may be), the same user always has the filenames, so when the same user user uses the service again, the newly generated files will ovewrite the previous ones and you won't have to clean-up/manage duplicates

Comment: It works!  But I did not use use-id at all, as I don't know how use-id can be involved into the generating of the unique id.  Could I ask how to use user-id to let the same user have the fixed uuid rather than creating a new file every time? @Pynchia

Comment: See my second comment above. You say you discriminate users based on their IP address, since they are not logged-in you system and not in any DB. Fine, you can use their IP address as the filename, one with .csv and one with .png (e.g. `80.145.10.208.csv` and `80.145.10.208.png`)